# Why does InnoDB do a full scan for COUNT(*)?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, innodb

In a table with 5 millions rows, a `SELECT count(*) FROM table` would be instant in MyISAM but would take several seconds in InnoDB.

Why is this that way? Why haven't they optimise count in InnoDB like MyISAM?

Thanks.

Comment: instead: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [an index]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a difference in implementation.  InnoDB supports transactions and therefore it has to count the rows based on your transactionally consistent view of the table(s).  Since MyISAM doesn't support ACID properties, if a row is inserted, it's inserted for everyone and therefore it can just update a count it keeps within the storage engine.

Comment: +1 scroll down and read Ken Jacob's post (5) http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Answer (score 6):

MyIsam has the number of rows stored somewhere and so the query is almost instant, InnoDB has to scan the table to get the full count.
If you have a conditional count ( Ex:  "SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE CUSTOMER =4" ) both have to do the scan and there is not much difference in this case

Source:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/