# MySQL COUNT(id) WHERE takes too long

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have an InnoDB table with around 7M rows and size of 4GB. The structure is below(col names are hidden):

[image: table structure]

When I run the query `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1 WHERE col7 != ''` it takes too long to return the count, somewhere between 50 and 70 seconds.
The `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` report is:
[image]

The `SELECT count(id) from table1` runs for about 5 seconds, but I need to use the `WHERE` clause too.
My question is are those speeds normal for a server, and what can be done to speed things up, particularly the second query.

The server is running MySQL v5.6.35.

Comment: Adding an index is the first thing to do

Comment: Add an index to `col7`

Comment: Add an index and avoid the `!=` operator. In your case you can rather do `> ''` it will run much faster

Comment: Don't use `COUNT(id)`, use `COUNT(*)`.  (This is only part of the solution.)

Answer (score 1):

To speed things up you need to add a non clustered index to the column you are making the where condition on .
This will allow your database to complete the query much faster.
To do so try this:

The statement shown here creates an index using the first 10 characters of the name column (assuming that name has a nonbinary string type):

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
```

resource: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Comment: A prefix index will probably be useless in this context.

Answer (score 1):

this is an evergreen question that was discussed in several discussions.

This is a typical issue of InnoDB engines

Try to have a look to these articles

[How to optimize COUNT(*) performance on InnoDB by using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267507/how-to-optimize-count-performance-on-innodb-by-using-index)

[Why does InnoDB do a full scan for COUNT(*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919427/why-does-innodb-do-a-full-scan-for-count)

http://kingori.co/minutae/2013/05/mysql-count-innodb/